# Test if component is rendered for the specific route

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-router-v4

I have a component like this:

```
const App = () =>
    <BrowserRouter basename={basePath}>
        <div>
            <Header/>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact component={Dashboard}/>
                <Route path="/contact" component={ContactForm}/>
                <Route path="*" component={Dashboard} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>;
```

And in my test I want to check that for the "/contact" route, App will indeed render ContactForm component. How can I do this?

If I try:

```
const wrapper = mount(
   <MemoryRouter initialEntries={[ '/contact' ]}>
      <App/>
   </MemoryRouter>
);
```

But this way wrapper also renders Dashboard so `expect(wrapper.find(ContactForm)).toHaveLength(1);` dont pass.

How should I check it properly?

---

**UPDATE**

This how I test it for now:

```
    const wrapper = mount(
        <MemoryRouter initialEntries={[ '/' ]}>
            <App/>
        </MemoryRouter>
    );
    wrapper.find("nav").find(Link).simulate("click", { button: 0 });
    expect(wrapper.find(ContactForm)).toHaveLength(1);
```

So I have to start with '/' route and then simulate a click on Link and then it works.

Answer (score 0):

`<MemoryRouter initialEntries={[ '/contact' ]}>`

This should work well...check what is value of props.location inside App component
May be BrowserRouter changes the location